# ASP.net VB How to not display MailMessage property if corresponding RadioButtonList has null value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.net VB email form with several radio buttons. I'm looking for VB code to make the unselected radio buttons and their corresponding text NOT display in the submitted email. Example:

If none of the ListItems in this RadioButtonList were selected-

```
<asp:RadioButtonList style="margin-right:24px; margin-bottom:5px" runat="server" id="Letterhead_Quantity" RepeatDirection="horizontal">     
     <asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="500" ></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="1000" ></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem style="display:none" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>`
```

Then this line of text on my code behind page in the MailMessage Properties would NOT be passed to the email message -

```
& "<b style=""font-family:Arial,Helvetica,San Serif;font-size:10pt"">Letterhead: </b>" & "<span style=""font-family:Arial,Helvetica,San Serif;font-size:10pt"">" & Letterhead_Quantity.Text & "</span>" _
& "<br>" _
```

I can't find anything on the Internet to address this and I'm not much of a programmer to create it myself, but I was hoping it could be something like:

```
If "Letterhead_Quantity is Null" 

Then hide "<b style=""font-family:Arial,Helvetica,San Serif;font-size:10pt"">Letterhead: text </b>..." 

Else "Display Letterhead: text"
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

When you're building your string just test whether the radio button was selected. I would use a string builder, but not required:

```
Dim message As New StringBuilder("first part blah blah...")

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Letterhead_Quantity.SelectedValue) Then
    message.Append("<b style=""font-family:Arial,Helvetica,San Serif;font-size:10pt"">Letterhead: text </b>...")
End If

message.Append("end part...")

myMailMessage = message.ToString()
```